# Each subtree sum in a binary tree in O(N) time and O(1) space?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, binary-tree

Given a binary tree, I want to return the maximum sum subtree's root.

Maximum Subtree: A subtree of the tree, whose sum of all its nodes is greater than that of the any other sub tree.

Edit: Node value is an integer.

I can do the following which takes O(n^2).

1. Calculate the sum of all nodes in the left subtree
2. Calculate the sum of all nodes in the right subtree
3. If sum of left subtree and right subtree and value of the root is greater than the current maximum sum, root is stored in the result
4. call this function recursively , with left subtree as root
5. call this function recursively , with right subtree as root.
   This will take O(n^2).

I can change it to a bottom up approach and use a hashmap to store the node to sum mapping which will make it O(N) but it will take O(N) space.

Is there any approach/method, that is O(N) time and O(1) space ?

Comment: Is a node a numeric value? Are there negative values in your tree?

Comment: Yes. Integer to be precise.

Comment: Can there be negative integer values as well?

Answer (score 3):

That's almost your solution, but takes O(n) and O(h) memory. You just visit each node only once.

```
calculateSum(vertex):
    if not vertex:
        return 0    
    sum = calculateSum(left) + calculateSum(right) + vertex.value
    if (sum > max)
        max = sum
    return sum
```

Comment: Note that space complexity is not O(1), due to calls stack getting increased with each recursive call.

Comment: @Novice you visit each node only once. In this algorithm for each node you call calculateSum for left and right children only once.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do it in `O(n)` with `O(h)` space if you calculate the sum on the fly. while iterating the tree. (In here, `h` is the maximal height of the tree, which is the size of the recursion stack).

Pseudo code:

```
TreeSum(v):
  if (v == null):
    return 0
  v_sum = TreeSum(v.left) + TreeSum(v.right) + v.value
  # max_sum is some global space variable holding the max_sum.
  # you hold only once such variable.  
  if v_sum > max_sum:
    max_sum = v_sum 
  return v_sum
```

When you are done, max_value hold the value of the maximal such sum.

If you also need the node itself, hold an extra variable which is a pointer to the relevant node, and is modified together with `max_sum`.

The idea is to do a [post order traversal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#Post-order) on the tree. First calculate the sum of each subtree, and only then - calculate the value of the root. 

While calculating the sum of each subtree, also modify max_sum when you find a new "best" subtree.